# Display data table for a pie chart in excel using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an excel data and able to draw an pie chart from vb.net.

I should be able to add the data table below the pie chart from vb.net

Thanks 
Rupesh

Comment: You're going to get a "What have you tried so far?" from someone. So you may as well say what you've tried so far. =)

Answer (score 0):

A **very useful** trick I learned a while back is if you open Excel, record macro and then step into it, you can usually see how to write the code or get something very close to what you'll need in .NET. For example, I created 4 columns like this:

```
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6
```

I went to the Developer tab and hit 'Record Macro' and then highlighted the cells and inserted a table. I then hit 'Stop Recording" and stepped into the macro by selecting it from the Macros list. It gave me this code:

```
Range("A1:D6").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$D$6"), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
```

You should be able to do something very similar in .NET using the interop. There are range and table objects in .NET that you can use and place the table where you like.

Hope this helps.